# Perplexing Django sqlite3 "unable to open database file" error

Tags: python, django

Been banging my head against this for a couple hours now.

So here's the story, I'm trying to spin up a Django-1.9.7 (using Python 2.7) application on a client's Windows machine. I've installed it successfully there before, and have made no changes to the database tables, models, or anything remotely touching the settings since the last successful installation.

So I copy over the files, then run `manage.py migrate` to generate the necessary tables. However, I get this error:

### Error Log

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Softrend\F3KWebApi\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 359, in database_forwards
    getattr(new_model._meta, self.option_name, set()),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 269, in alter_unique_together
    self._remake_table(model, override_uniques=new_unique_together)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 197, in _remake_table
    self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 110, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 323, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

And here are the relevant settings:

## `settings.py`

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# ...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I can see the `db.sqlite3` being correctly created where it's supposed to be, but this error still persists. Any attempt for code to access these tables results in errors that say the tables don't exist (eg. `auth_user`).

I've looked through just about every one of the SO questions related to this and followed [this guide](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes#DjangosaysUnabletoOpenDatabaseFilewhenusingSQLite3) but I've yet to find a solution.

Keep in mind that I can run the exact same `migrate` command on my own machine just fine with the *exact* same files.

Any help is appreciated!

## EDITS

- Yes, I've tried explicitly setting the `NAME` parameter to an absolute directory path to the file (eg. `'C:\\webapi\\db.sqlite3'`)
- Yes, I've verified that the `BASE_DIR` is correct.

Comment: Could you try to remove the `os.path.join` part and leave only the name itself and see if that'll work?

Comment: Are you certain that `BASE_DIR` is being generated properly to the value you are looking for? Have you tried printing it out to see its value?

Comment: @table - I tried explicitly setting it and it doesn't work either.

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm - I've printed it out and verified that it is in fact the expected directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, no idea why this works, but I did this and it sorted it out:

```
manage.py flush
manage.py migrate
```

I had manually deleted the file (`db.sqlite3`) before, which I'm assuming is the same thing as `manage.py flush`, but maybe I'm wrong.